# How to get row which has max date from a dataset using rowfilter in NET 1.1 C#

Tags: c#

I have a dataset, let's say "ds". This dataset contains only one table, and this table may have 1 or more rows.

I need to filter rows and get the row with min datetime and at the same time with a specific value for another field, for example, condition for rowfilter would be:

```
Min(DateTimeField) and anotherField=12
```

I am using RowFilter feature as below (for one field):

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="anotherField=12"
```

but taken into account the datetime field I am trying to do below:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="anotherField=12 and Min(DateTimeField)"
```

but how to pass to rowfilter datetime field from this:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateTimeField"]
```

I am not sure if Min(DateTimeField) within rowfilter is working.

So how can I filter dataset rows and get only one with min datetime and anotherField=12?

**UPDATE**:

Using filter below:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="anotherField=12 and Min(DateTimeField)"
```

I am getting below exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in system.data.dll

Additional information: Cannot perform 'And' operation on System.Boolean and System.DateTime.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested.
But suggest you to first compute `Min(DateTimeField)` using DataTable Compute

```
  DateTime minDateVal = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Compute("Min(DateTimeField)", "anotherField = 12");
```

Then apply you row Filter using `minDateVal`

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "anotherField=12 and DateTimeField='" + minDateVal + "'";

ds.Tables[0] = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. In my case, initially before applying rowFilter I have two rows, and after applying it I should have 1 row, so Why am I getting ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 2 after applying rowfilter?

Comment: @user1624552 You are getting 2 rows because you are not assigned filtered view to datatable. check my edit

Comment: this is working from .NET Framework 2.0 and above but not in .NET 1.1 since ToTable is not available in .NET 1.1. I am modifying a legacy project in Visual Studio 2003 and .NET 1.1.

Comment: I accept your answer as the correct because here what I am trying to do is filter data.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, you have a syntax mistake in your filter expression, it should be

```
"anotherField=12 and DateTimeField=Min(DateTimeField)"
```

instead of

```
"anotherField=12 and Min(DateTimeField)"
```

Comment: the problem is that applying "anotherField=12 and Min(DateTimeField)" to dataset rowfilter I am getting an exception. See my update.

Comment: Ok, then the DateTime / boolean mismatch is exactly the syntax error that I'm suggesting to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of ways to do it, if you want to use Linq you can do:

```
DataRow dr = (from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
         where (int)r["anotherField"] == 12
         orderby r["dateTimeField"] ascending
         select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

For this to work, you need to add reference to "System.Data.DatasetExtension" to your project if you don't have one.

Also this needs .Net Framework 4.0, so it won't help op. But I'll leave it here in case somebody finds it helpfull.

Comment: sorry I am using net 1.1, it is a legacy project.

Comment: @user1624552 Ah ok :)

Comment: how can I do what you say using net 1.1?